# Remove conferenceData of event calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-hangouts

I am using createRequest of `conferenceData` to create a `hangout` link for the event calendar.
Now I want to remove `conferenceData` of the event when update by API but I can't find how to do that.

Please help me.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You will need to edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the event object set `'conferenceData': null` and set `'conferenceDataVersion': 1` in inset API call like this,

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'conferenceDataVersion': 1,
                'resource': event
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `conferenceData: None` inside your request body.